# Chatter Answers trigger not available in Eclipse - no access to trigger I know is there

Tags: trigger, permissions, ide, eclipse

I need to correct a known issue with Chatter Answers and one of the triggers that needs modification (chatter_answers_question_escalation_to_case_trigger) is unavailabe in Eclipse, i.e. I can't access it. I've gone through all the object permissions/class permission, etc. in Salesforce on my profile and nothing seems to be working. I have system admin access. Does anyone understand why I wouldn't be able to see this trigger in IDE?

Comment: what version is your IDE plugin?please use latest version

Comment: as far as I know I'm on the latest version: 2.0.2 for Eclipse IDE and 31.0.0 for Force IDE. there are no new updates for me to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the metadata in your project by right clicking on your project then from the force.com menu select "Add/Remove Metadata Components". Then click the refresh button in the top right hand corner to expand the trigger folder and see if you see it listed and verify that it is checked. [image: force menu]. [image]